# Как в json.dumps включить/отключить экранирование "/"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, экранирование

**Не могу слеш отэкранировать при преобразовании в JSON**. (Python 3.7, Linux)

Сейчас `'/'` нужно `'\/'`

Преобразую словарь в JSON

```
d = json.dumps(dic) - слеши в путях к файлам "/" не экранируются
```

пробую предварительно `path = path_raw.replace('/', '\\/')`

на выхлопе экран из 4(!) обратных слешей `\\\\/`.

Нашел интересный пакет [ujson](https://github.com/esnme/ultrajson/blob/master/README.rst), у него есть опция отключения экранирования слеша, но и она не работает, 
перепробовал кучу комбинаций с разными кавычками и `\r'\/'` и `'\\/'` и `'\\r\/'`.

Comment: Зачем экранировать прямые слеши?

Comment: экранирование слеша нужно для экспорта кук в json формате в chrome, в примере cookie в json, который я нашел, слеш экранирован, попробовал без экранирования импортировать с помошью плагина для хрома  не принимает, вот и мучаюсь

Comment: Вы боретесь с ветряными мельницами, json есть json, не нужно его допиливать

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй вот так хаком

```
json.dumps(your_dict).replace('/', r'\/')

>>>    escaped = json.dumps({"path": "/home/com/part/"}).replace('/', r'\/')
>>>    escaped
       '{"path": "\\/home\\/com\\/part\\/"}'
>>>    first_dict = json.loads(escaped)
>>>    first_dict
       {'path': '/home/com/part/'}
```

Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129681/json-dumps-escaping-forward-slashes) описывается подобный случай.

Comment: К сожалению, не получается, json.dumps()
 экранирует выражение когда не нужно"path": "\\/" и почему то не экранирует, когда нужно

Comment: Поправил добавил пример

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы после дампа было экранирование, но только одним обратным слешем, а в вашем примере получается, после дампа 2 слеша, после извлечения все возвращается в исходное. Но я не буду извлекать из дампа. Мне нужно, чтобы было так: {"path": "\/com\/"}. Это не путь к файлу, это куки. В любом случае спасибо за участие и идеи.

Comment: @MikhailKuligin, это экранирование одним слешом. Если в примере из этого ответа сделать `print(escaped)`, то получится `{"path": "\/home\/com\/part\/"}`.

Comment: Спасибо, Вы правы! Проблема с лишними слешами появляется на этапе добавления словарей в список, до этого все получается как нужно: получаю словари, там один слеш, делаю json.dumps(dic).replace('/', r'\/') слеш экранируется: {"path": "\/home\/com\/part\/"}. А вот при преобразовании в список словарей появляется второй экранирующий слеш "path": "\\/complete\\/search". Теперь нужно как то это побороть.

Answer (score 1):

**Пришел вот к такому решению:**

```
dic = {'path': /path}
listofdic.append(dic)
dump_list = json.dumps(listofdic).replace('/', r'\/')
str_to_write = str(dump_list)
write_file(json_file, str_to_write)
```

в файле после записи (показываю только проблемный кусок):

```
"path": "\/complete\/search"
```

Comment: `JSON.parse('"\/"') === JSON.parse('"/"')`